# I get 504 Deadline Exceeded in Apache Beam using ReadFromSpanner

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am building an application in Apache Beam and Python that runs in Google DataFlow. I am using the `ReadFromSpanner` method in `apache_beam.io.gcp.experimental.spannerio`. This works for most of my Spanner tables but the really large ones that are >16m rows tend to fail due to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 63, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 64, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 79, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 80, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 84, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 359, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 221, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 261, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 268, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 359, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 221, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 719, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1241, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1306, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1401, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 221, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 719, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1241, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1306, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1401, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 221, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 719, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1241, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1321, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 446, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1374, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/experimental/spannerio.py", line 550, in process
    for row in read_action(element['partitions']):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_v1/streamed.py", line 143, in __iter__
    self._consume_next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_v1/streamed.py", line 116, in _consume_next
    response = six.next(self._response_iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_v1/snapshot.py", line 45, in _restart_on_unavailable
    for item in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 116, in next
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded [while running 'Read from Spanner/Read From Partitions']
```

From my understanding this error comes from the `ReadFromSpanner` operation as it's workers have timed out.

To solve this I have tried the following:

- Changed the `num_workers` and `disk_size_gb` and added the `--experiments=shuffle_mode=service` flag as suggested in [Google's Common error guidance](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#tsg-rpc-timeout)
- Changed the Machine Type from `n1-standard-1` to `n1-standard-2` from [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n1_machine_types)

My latest code is attached below. I am including `Transformation` for simple data wrangling in the rows.

```
 """Set pipeline arguments."""
    options = PipelineOptions(
        region=RUNNER_REGION,
        project=RUNNER_PROJECT_ID,
        runner=RUNNER,
        temp_location=TEMP_LOCATION,
        job_name=JOB_NAME,
        service_account_email=SA_EMAIL,
        setup_file=SETUP_FILE_PATH,
        disk_size_gb=500,
        num_workers=10,
        machine_type="n1-standard-2",
        save_main_session=True)

    """Build and run the pipeline."""
        with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
            (p
             | "Read from Spanner" >> ReadFromSpanner(SPANNER_PROJECT_ID, SPANNER_INSTANCE_ID, SPANNER_DB, sql=QUERY)
             | "Transform elements into dictionary" >> beam.ParDo(Transformation)
             | "Write new records to BQ" >> WriteToBigQuery(
                 BIGQUERY_TABLE,
                 schema=SCHEMA,
                 write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                 create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                 )
```

A **potential solution** is to edit the timeout control; I have seen this being available in Java but not in Python. How can I edit timeout control in Python or is there any other solution to this issue?

Comment: The SpannerIO uses the Session API in the implementation. Does setting the `google.cloud.spanner_v1.session.DEFAULT_RETRY_TIMEOUT_SECS` work? See Spanner docs at https://googleapis.dev/python/spanner/latest/session-api.html

Comment: I have passed it in like so: `ReadFromSpanner(SPANNER_PROJECT_ID, SPANNER_INSTANCE_ID, SPANNER_DB, sql=QUERY, DEFAULT_RETRY_TIMEOUT_SECS=600)`  and i get the following error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'DEFAULT_RETRY_TIMEOUT_SECS'`

Comment: I am trying to create my own `pool` session that can include the default timeout.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was trying to set that default somewhere in your code.S o add `google.cloud.spanner_v1.session.DEFAULT_RETRY_TIMEOUT_SECS = 600` before you run the pipeline. Let us know how using the pool session goes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't change the behaviour. I am now testing passing a pool parameter, first with `PingingPool` and then with `TransactionPingingPool`. I will drop a message on the results.

Comment: I have tried using the `PingingPool` with `background = threading.Thread(target=background_loop, name='ping-pool')` as described in here: https://googleapis.dev/python/spanner/latest/advanced-session-pool-topics.html but the app lasted around 15 minutes without ingesting data so I manually stopped it. Using the `FixedSizePool` with a custom timeout did not work either.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @regeter I solved the issue. Will post the solution as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted this [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner/issues/261) in the `googleapis/python-spanner` repo. The maintainers of the library were able to help me out and include retry and timeout options for reads and queries.

To solve the problem I reverse engineered the [Apache Beam Spanner connector](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.31.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/experimental/spannerio.html#create_transaction), `apache_beam.io.gcp.experimental.spannerio`. Specifically the `_ReadFromPartitionFn` to include the timeout option.

I included the following code that will run create read partition objects from Spanner and then read from those partition objects. Note that I am using the `timeout` variable in `process_query_batch` within `readSpannerPartitions`.

```
class createSpannerReadPartitions(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, SPANNER_CONFIG):
        self.project = SPANNER_CONFIG['spanner_project']
        self.instance = SPANNER_CONFIG['spanner_instance']
        self.db = SPANNER_CONFIG['spanner_database']
        self.query = SPANNER_CONFIG['query']

    def setup(self):
        spanner_client = spanner.Client(self.project)
        spanner_instance = spanner_client.instance(self.instance)
        spanner_db = spanner_instance.database(self.db)
        self.snapshot = spanner_db.batch_snapshot()
        self.snapshot_dict = self.snapshot.to_dict()

    def process(self, element):
        partitioning_action = self.snapshot.generate_query_batches

        for p in partitioning_action(self.query):
            yield {
                "partitions": p,
                "transaction_info": self.snapshot_dict}


class readSpannerPartitions(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, SPANNER_CONFIG):
        self.project = SPANNER_CONFIG['spanner_project']
        self.instance = SPANNER_CONFIG['spanner_instance']
        self.db = SPANNER_CONFIG['spanner_database']
        self.query = SPANNER_CONFIG['query']

    def setup(self):
        spanner_client = spanner.Client(self.project)
        spanner_instance = spanner_client.instance(self.instance)
        self.spanner_db = spanner_instance.database(self.db)
        self.snapshot = self.spanner_db.batch_snapshot()
        self.snapshot_dict = self.snapshot.to_dict()

    def process(self, element):
        self.snapshot = BatchSnapshot.from_dict(
            self.spanner_db, element['transaction_info'])

        read_action = self.snapshot.process_query_batch
        for row in read_action(element['partitions'], timeout=86400):
            yield row

    def teardown(self):
        self.snapshot.close()
```

I then created the pipeline like so

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    p_read = (p | beam.Create(["Start pipeline"])
                | 'Generate Partitions' >> beam.ParDo(createSpannerReadPartitions(SPANNER_CONFIG))
                | 'Reshuffle' >> beam.Reshuffle()
                | 'Read From Partitions' >> beam.ParDo(readSpannerPartitions(SPANNER_CONFIG)))
    
    return p_read
```

This has been possible thanks to maintainers of the `googleapis/python-spanner` repo.

Comment: Would you consider contributing the fix to Beam ? https://beam.apache.org/contribute/

Comment: Happy to @chamikara I'll follow the guide this weekend and create a PR with my solution. I had created this ticket in the Apache Beam Jira board a few months back - could be closed then https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11956